# set emacs for python

Tags: python, emacs

i'm new to emacs, and I want to use it for programing in python. Most important thing for me is autocomplete. I want a step by step tutorial for add a python autocomplete plug-in for emacs 24.

sorry for my bad English.

Comment: Used this: https://github.com/jorgenschaefer/elpy for some time, and am happy about it, but I'm rather casual user. The above is also installable through MELPA repository.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This Python-focused Emacs resource discusses installing and configuring auto-complete and other useful configuration for Python work in Emacs:

http://www.jesshamrick.com/2012/09/18/emacs-as-a-python-ide/

Answer (score 0):

You will find all information here:

http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/?action=browse;oldid=PythonMode;id=PythonProgrammingInEmacs